# Memory profile a debug apk on an Android device without its source code?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, memory-profiling

I have a debug apk with me but not its source code. Is it possible to memory profile the apk using Android studio, adb or *any other tool* on a Macbook?

I just want to see the memory or RAM usage of my apk while it is running. A view like described in official developer.android.com [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler#record-allocations) would be so much helpful. Is it possible to get this detailed view with just a debug apk but not source code?

For the above to be possible. Should the apk have `android:debuggable="true"` declared in its `AndroidManifest.xml` file? Lets say even this is in place. Is it possible to memory profile the apk? If yes then how?

**Environment:**
Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 1 running on macOS Catalina